# Switch to and click through cookie banners with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-crawler

I've tried to deny the cookies on this website with the common **find_element** instruction, but it doesn't work and gives me a **NoSuchElementException**.
My attempt to switch to the new banner puts out the following: 
**WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable**
Can someone please help me out on this problem?

##### Imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

##### Code

```
pagelink = 'https://www.mitsubishi-les.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('[mypath]')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(pagelink)
time.sleep(3)

try:
    # the common way
    driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="focus-lock-id"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
except:
    print('NoSuchElementException')
    try:
        wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="focus-lock-id"]/div[2]')))
        driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="focus-lock-id"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
    except:
        print('WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a work around of the problem. You can make python click through it.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y) #Move a mouse to (x, y) coordinates on your screen. 
pyautogui.click()
```

[Pyautogui documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#mouse.on_click)

To get your mouse coordinates use:

```
pyautogui.position()
```

There is also little bit more lightweighted option
[python mouse documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse).